# Android sqlite searching two columns

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting a bit confused on how to search two separate columns.
I am using sqlite.

```
Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "firstName LIKE ? OR lastName LIKE ?" , new String[]{"%" + name + "%", "%" + name + "%"}, null, null, null);
```

When i search using for say Joe Bob, with that query i can do

'Joe' returns Joe Bob

'Bob' returns Joe Bob

But not 'Joe Bob'

So just want to find a way to search for firstName ' ' lastName but i am having no luck

Comment: Did you try `"firstName + ' ' + lastName like ?"` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only 1 argument:

```
Cursor cursor = qb.query(
    db, 
    sqlSelect, 
    "firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
    new String[]{"%" + name + "%"}, 
    null, null, null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to concatenate the first and last names.

You can does this using **`||`** so your underlying query could be :-

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, firstName||' '||lastName AS name_in_full WHERE firstName LIKE ? OR lastName LIKE ?
```

- that the ? represents a value as supplied (so the above, as it is wouldn't work as expected).
- you may or may not you want the firstName and lastName columns in the resultant Cursor
- the cursor will have a column named **name_in_full** and it is this column that will have both names concatenated.

For use by the **query** method you would set **sqlSelect** to be

**`sqlSelect = "firstName,lastName,firstName||' '||lastName AS name_in_full";`**

- *omitting firstName and lastname and the respective separating comma as required*

## Alternative interpretation of Question

If what you want is to find and only a combination of both e.g. you had rows such as

```
Bob Hope
Joe Joe
Bob Bob
Joe Bob
```

and you want to find the 1 ***Joe Bob*** row i.e. **Joe Bob** but no other rows then instead of **OR** use **AND**

i.e.

```
Cursor cursor = qb.query(
    db, 
    sqlSelect, 
    "firstName LIKE ? AND lastName LIKE ?", //<<<<<<<<<< OR change to AND
    new String[]{"%" + name + "%", "%" + name + "%"}, 
    null, null, null
);
```